# How to create a schema for the purpose of re-testing records?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my current schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d0290

```
CREATE TABLE `Rooms` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RoomDescription VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MinTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    MaxTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `Rooms` (RoomDescription, MinTemperature, MaxTemperature) VALUES
('Room 1', 10, 20),
('Room 2', 15, 20);

CREATE TABLE `Records` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DateRecorded TIMESTAMP,
    RoomId INT NOT NULL,
    ActualTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    IsValid INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomId) REFERENCES `Rooms`(Id)
);

INSERT INTO `Records` (DateRecorded, RoomId, ActualTemperature, IsValid) VALUES
('2021-09-28 08:00:00', 1, 8, 0),
('2021-09-28 08:01:00', 2, 15, 1),
('2021-09-29 08:00:00', 1, 17, 1),
('2021-09-29 08:01:00', 2, 19, 1);

SELECT * FROM `Rooms`;
SELECT * FROM `Records`;

-- Rooms
Id  RoomDescription MinTemperature  MaxTemperature
1   Room 1          10              20
2   Room 2          15              20

-- Records
Id  DateRecorded          RoomId    ActualTemperature   IsValid
1   2021-09-28 08:00:00   1         8                   0
2   2021-09-28 08:01:00   2         15                  1
3   2021-09-29 08:00:00   1         17                  1
4   2021-09-29 08:01:00   2         19                  1
```

**Summary**

Rooms table: Displays it's `RoomDescription` and it's `Minimum` and `Maximum` values for the temperature allowed for the specific room.

Records table: Displays all records recorded. It references which `RoomId` has been recorded along with it's `ActualTemperature`. Then for the `IsValid` column, if the value is between `Min` and `Max` then it's a `Valid` record. If it's out of specification, this means it's an `InValid` record.

**Goal**

I need to find a way of re testing `InValid` records and keeping the history of previous results.

**What I think is a good approach**

I believe one of the ways to achieve my goal is to create a new table: `ReTest-Records`.

```
CREATE TABLE `ReTest-Records` (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    DateRecorded TIMESTAMP,
    RecordId INT NOT NULL,
    ActualTemperature DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    IsValid INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (RecordId) REFERENCES `Records`(Id)
);

INSERT INTO `ReTest-Records` (DateRecorded, RecordId, ActualTemperature, IsValid) VALUES
('2021-09-28 12:30:00', 1, 4, 0), -- ReTest 1
('2021-09-28 16:30:00', 1, 10, 1); -- ReTest 2
```

Here, I am able to match up the table: `ReTest-Records` to `Records` table. Which allows me to see whether the re-test is valid or invalid using the following query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM `Records` r
JOIN `ReTest-Records` rt ON r.Id = rt.RecordId
WHERE r.IsValid = 0 AND rt.IsValid = 1;
```

The output of the above query will mean 2 of the following things:

1. Record not been retested.
2. Record is still invalid.

Then within my C# application I am able to display this record for a `ReTest`.

In terms of viewing the history of records + retests, I can run this query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM `Records` r
LEFT JOIN `ReTest-Records` rt ON r.Id = rt.RecordId;
```

**Question**

I'd like to know if this approach is an appropriate way of recording re tested records? It might be a case that, I do not need to build an extra table and can simply modify my existing tables.